# Fortify and tidy (from broom) cause polygons to not be correct

Tags: r, ggplot2, shapefile, map-projections, broom

I am attempting to use a map of Lesotho and plot various other data on it. The shapefile I pulled is the ESRI file from this link:
http://www.mapmaker.com/maplibrary/library/stacks/Africa/Lesotho/index.htm

When I import the shapefile via readOGR and then plot it with the base plot function, the polygons are in the appropriate orientation. As soon as I use fortify or tidy, they are no longer in the correct orientation. I have included the code below. Please note I only included the tidy code below, but have also tried with fortify with the same issue.

I have tried specifying the proj4string (which is fine in this shape file) and I tried spTransform, but neither one then has the correct orientation of the districts when I plot with ggplot. I'm not sure what other information to include that might be helpful... I'm in R 3.4.4. Any and all help appreciated!!

```
s1 <- readOGR(".","LSO_adm1")
summary(s1)
plot(s1) #This is actually what the districts in Lesotho look like
s2 <- tidy(s1)
ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data = s2, aes(x=lat, y=long, group=group), col="black") 
#This is then some sort of weird alternative Lesotho
```

Comment: You have your longitude and latitude mixed up in geom_polygon. It should be (x = long, y = lat, group = group)

Comment: AHHHHH thank you!!! I can't believe it was so simple....